# `pip3 freeze` prints many packages at the beginning

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I created `virtualenv` and commanded `pip3 freeze` because I'm using `python3` to run my project.

```
virtualenv .
source bin/activate
pip3 freeze
```

However, `pip3 freeze` printed default(?) python3 packages even though I didn't install any packages yet:

```
backports.weakref==1.0rc1
bleach==1.5.0
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
configparser==3.5.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==1.11.12
django-allauth==0.32.0
django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
django-filter==1.0.4
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
djangorestframework==3.7.7
enum34==1.1.6
flake8==3.4.1
flake8-docstrings==1.1.0
flake8-polyfill==1.0.1
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.5
Keras==2.0.6
Markdown==2.6.8
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.13.1
oauthlib==2.0.2
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.2.1
protobuf==3.3.0
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pydocstyle==2.0.0
pyflakes==1.5.0
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2018.3
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.18.3
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
scipy==0.19.1
six==1.10.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
tensorflow==1.2.1
Theano==0.9.0
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

Obviously I don't want to install tensorflow and Theano for my virtual machine. :(

**Why does it have default(?) python3 packages? Can we start it from scratch?**

Comment: are you on a production server?

Comment: I'm on my mac computer.  I left my desktop in another state and I can't pick it up until the end of August. The Desktop was using Ubuntu.

Comment: python> `import scipy` - if that or any other import from the list works, then you **DO** have packages installed.

Comment: But I can't run django here

Comment: `Django`? or `django`?

Comment: Why do I need to import `corsheaders`.. uhha.. it's the package that I had to install at the beginning

Comment: It would've been better if you formed your comments in one sentence to express what you want instead of commenting excessively

Comment: `django` works fine but I'm getting bunch of `No module named ` errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have the packages if you can `import` them.

`import sys` and then check `print(sys.path)` for which directories have your packages in them.

Typically a directory like `site-packages` will be listed.

You can `pip3 uninstall <package>` what you don't want and if needed, delete from the `site-packages` directory. But `pip3 uninstall` is the preferred option.

Note that you can also learn about your package location by doing something like : `pip3 show numpy`

Which prints:

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.14.3
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: scipy, pandas
```

Comment: `import sys` and then `print(sys.path)` for a list of directories. Find the one that includes `site-packages` and that will tell you the location. It's usually something like `'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages'`

Comment: This is result `'/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages'`

Comment: Ok so there you can either delete the packages you don't want, or use pip. I recommend pip but you can delete from the directory if pip fails for some reason

Comment: But isn't `pip` for `python2.6`? I used `pip3` because my `django` project works on `python3.x`. Shouldn't I keep using `pip3`? I need to command `python3 manage.py runserver`

Comment: Is deleting file list on the `site-packages` and delete all packages would work?

Comment: sorry I just say pip to mean whichever pip you are using. If you delete the folders INSIDE site-packages, that will remove them from your list of installed packages

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I think by “default packages” you mean the standard library that ships with the interpreter. Many of those packages are not standard library packages. So that leads be me to believe that the problem is that the virtual env was not set up correctly and that your pip 3 binary is pointing at the global packages already installed.

Let’s clarify and confirm a few things. A virtual environment is nothing more that changing shell configurations to point to the installed python interpreter local to the directory it’s configured for. Because of this when your virtual environment is activated, you should get both a shell indication next your prompt indicating which env is activated and you can also run a command to see which pip installation your shell would default to.

I would do the following, first run this command in your shell when your virtualenvironment is activated:

```
which pip3
```

This will tell you the exact pip bearing used. If it points to the one in your virtual environment then great! If not, let’s redo this by using the built in python 3 module for venv:

```
python -m venv venv
```

This will set up a venv named venv(this is convention, you can name it anything)

Activate it:

```
source venv/lib/activate
```

Then check it again:

```
Which pip3
```

Let me know the results

Comment: both prints : `/usr/local/bin/pip3`;

Comment: Then that’s definitely not your venv, I did type the command wrong for activating it. use source venv/bin/activate, and tell me if your shell changes, it should mark the venv next to your prompt

Comment: oh.. no module name `venv`. I don't use `venv` though..?? I would rather stick with `virtualenv`. I'm not familiar wiht `venv`. Do you think it's worth it?

Comment: Also, it did the venv command make a folder with venv in it etc? I noticed you are using the python3 binary so repeat seps with that.

Comment: I'm not sure What you meant by seps. :P

Comment: Sorry I mean steps haha. Also the module venv is the same thing, it was just moved into python itself in python 3

Comment: Oh I see. No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

If you check with `which pip3` you will see `/usr/bin/pip3` instead of your virtualenv.

I recommend for new projects to have a separate folder for virtualenv. In a case like this one (or who knows) will be easier to make a copy/rename/delete it.

My solution:

1. first `deactivate`
2. upgrade virtualenv `pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv`
3. rename your virtualenv (just in case).
4. install a new virtualenv `virtualenv -p python3 uenv`
5. activate virtualenv `source uenv/bin/activate`
6. check with `pip3 freeze` to be sure is empty
7. install from file `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

You should be OK now. If you check with `which pip3` you will see your virtualenv.

You can delete the old virtualenv.

This method allows you to write/read packages from file (`requirements.txt`), without manually editing the file. Manually editing requirements.txt is bad habbit and can lead to errors.